# Is there any way to load the configuration in Spring Boot application for one time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I'm looking for some recommendations or best practices to implement the unit test of spring boot application.

I have multiple classes of unit test and in each of those classes, I need to add the configuration like :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplication.class)
public class ServiceRequestControllerTest{
...
}
```

So, when I run the goal maven test (`mvn clean test`), the spring configuration is loaded for multiple times. For example, I have five unit test classes, so, it loads the configuration five times which is slowing down the building of the project.

The question:  is there any way to load this configuration just for one time for all the unit test classes?

Comment: any suggestion ???

Answer (score 2):

use `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. the default behaviour for it is to reuse the context between tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringBootApplication.class)
public class ServiceRequestControllerTest{
...
}
```

Comment: i tested it and does not work, i think we can't use the runner class springBootApp.class inside with annotation contextConfiguration because it's not a configuration it's a runner

Answer (score 1):

We must always handle exceptions since it allows us to have greater contingency control. It is also necessary to always use JSON as a basis for Rest responses so we would have something like this:

```
@RestController
public class ControllerAddress {

    @PostMapping("/address")
    public ResponseEntity<?> postAddress(@RequestBody String address) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            response.put("state", true);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.put("message", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

But if you don't want to use JSON and you want a boolean variable true / false to respond directly, you can change the lines:

```
response.put("state", true);
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

for:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: sorry but your response is for another subject not what i'm looking for, Thanks.